# Ionic Active PushNotification after login in the app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, authentication, ionic-framework

Im new in Ionic and angularjs. I'm trying to develop an android app which can receive pushnotifications with the cordova push notification plugin ( here the plugin's link https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)

I followed many tutorials and my app can receive push notifications. The problem is the next:

I want to take the device token, user id, user name etcetc, **once the user has logged in**. I want to know what are the next steps that I have to do

Here is my actually working code for receive push notification without login.

[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8VTz.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android push notifications use the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) service for sending push notification. U need GCM sender ID and Push notification service Provider Api( For sending push notification to mobile as server). Ionic provides free push notification service "Ionic Push". For more details,

http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-overview

For android setup for push notification, use this link ( For Step 1 for all push notification API and follow step 2 for ionic)

http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-android-setup

For Integration with push notification api like Ionic Push, AWS SNS,Parse Push .. etc. User need to get "push device id" ( Unique id for device based user app and Push Id)

```
module.run(function($cordovaPush) {

      var androidConfig = {
        "senderID": "replace_with_sender_id",
      };

      document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
        $cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {
          // Success
        }, function(err) {
          // Error
        })

        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
          switch(notification.event) {
            case 'registered':
              if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
                alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
              }
              break;

            case 'message':
              // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
              alert('message = ' + notification.message + ' msgCount = ' + notification.msgcnt);
              break;

            case 'error':
              alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
              break;

            default:
              alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
              break;
          }
        });


        // WARNING: dangerous to unregister (results in loss of tokenID)
        $cordovaPush.unregister(options).then(function(result) {
          // Success!
        }, function(err) {
          // Error
        })
      }, false);
    });
```

Comment: Yep, I saw this before in the ngCordova's documentation but I cant understand what i should put into "replace_with_sender_id".  All the previous steps I followed for develop my app also and it works. Anyways Im not sure that this is the answer for my problem because this works when the app starts and I want read the notification if I logged into my app first. Thanks anyway, I hope that I could find the answer soon :(